# Can't append a link element to an iframe with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm building a web app to make my business more automated with HTML/CSS/jQuery in the front end and python in the backend .

I wrote an easy script with jQuery that call a route with ajax and recieve the data as json and after that parse it and return a list of iframes depending on it's length : If we have 20 items in that list and we want 5 items per page, create 4 pages and put 5 iframes in each link .

Here's the code responsible for this feature :

```
        $('.pageContent').empty()
                        for (var i = 0; i < vidPageList.length; i++){
                            var videoUrl = vidPageList[i].videoLink
                            var postUrl = vidPageList[i].postLink
                            console.log(postUrl)
                            $('<iframe src ="'+videoUrl+'" class = "videoEntry" width = "360" height = "250"></iframe>').appendTo( ".pageContent" )
                            $('<a class = "postLink" href = "'+postUrl+'"> Video link </a>').appendTo(".videoEntry")
                        }
```

**The problem:**

iframes are added perfectly but the links are not added at all, I don't know why, the console is not showing me any error, I tried to debug the values of `postUrl` and they are all correct, why is it doing this ? It looks like the last line responsible for adding the link is not working, I also tried to add everything with one `appendTo()` call but it only added iframes, what I'm missing here ?

Comment: Iframes create their own window. You have to get inside that iframe window first...after it has loaded. You can't append directly to the iframe element itself and if the iframe is from different domain you can't access it at all unless you control code inside the iframe page

Comment: and If I use a div and add to it an iframe and append the link to that div?

Comment: Are these url's even from same domain as page? Using jQuery if is from same domain can get inside iframe using `contents()` ... after the iframe has loaded though

Comment: Cant you just create this in one line?

Comment: @charlietfl No they aren't .

Comment: Anis....you can't access inside them at all then due to *"same origin policy"* security restriction

Comment: perhaps you should also clarify what expected result is. Are you wanting link outside the iframe? If so that's not what `appendTo(iframe)` would do and can be done. Going inside the iframe can not be done

Answer (score 0):

The first time your selectors ran, there was no .videoEntry class because it is in the iframe. It may be useful to first make all your html content before appending.